# How to fix 'Import error: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException:' while using neo4j-admin import

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j-admin import to read the csv and create nodes. While firing up the command for the import I am facing a file lock exception. 
My import csv file -

```
movieId:ID,title,year:int,:LABEL
tt0133093,"The Matrix",1999,Movie
tt0234215,"The Matrix Reloaded",2003,Movie;Sequel
tt0242653,"The Matrix Revolutions",2003,Movie;Sequel
```

I have already tried to kill the process and still the problem pertains.

Command while running the import - 
`/bin/neo4j-admin import --nodes=test_new_import.csv`

ERROR :

```
Import error: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: This file is locked by another process, please ensure you don't have another Neo4j process or tool using it: '/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore'.'
Caused by:org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: This file is locked by another process, please ensure you don't have another Neo4j process or tool using it: '/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore'.'
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: This file is locked by another process, please ensure you don't have another Neo4j process or tool using it: '/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore'.'
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:217)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.<init>(NeoStores.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:129)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.openAllNeoStores(StoreFactory.java:93)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.store.BatchingNeoStores.instantiateStores(BatchingNeoStores.java:237)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.store.BatchingNeoStores.createNew(BatchingNeoStores.java:181)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:87)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.doImport(ImportTool.java:581)
        at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.CsvImporter.doImport(CsvImporter.java:128)
        at org.neo4j.commandline.dbms.ImportCommand.execute(ImportCommand.java:236)
        at org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool.execute(AdminTool.java:127)
        at org.neo4j.commandline.admin.AdminTool.main(AdminTool.java:51)
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: VM pause monitor is not started
                at org.neo4j.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:142)
                at org.neo4j.kernel.monitoring.VmPauseMonitor.stop(VmPauseMonitor.java:71)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.OnDemandDetailsExecutionMonitor.done(OnDemandDetailsExecutionMonitor.java:128)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.MultiExecutionMonitor.done(MultiExecutionMonitor.java:82)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.MultiExecutionMonitor.done(MultiExecutionMonitor.java:82)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ImportLogic.close(ImportLogic.java:520)
                at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:99)
                ... 5 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: This file is locked by another process, please ensure you don't have another Neo4j process or tool using it: '/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore'.'
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.acquireLock(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:227)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapper.<init>(SingleFilePageSwapper.java:178)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.createPageSwapper(SingleFilePageSwapperFactory.java:66)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPagedFile.<init>(MuninnPagedFile.java:149)
        at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.map(MuninnPageCache.java:412)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.MetaDataStore.getRecord(MetaDataStore.java:285)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.NeoStores.verifyRecordFormat(NeoStores.java:198)
        ... 11 more

WARNING Import failed. The store files in /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db are left as they are, although they are likely in an unusable state. Starting a database on these store files will likely fail or observe inconsistent records so start at your own risk or delete the store manually
unexpected error: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.FileLockException: This file is locked by another process, please ensure you don't have another Neo4j process or tool using it: '/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/neostore'.'
```

Comment: Is it open in excel or other programs?

Comment: it is a csv file. I even tried it with this command
/bin/neo4j-admin import --mode=csv --database=graph.db --nodes=test_new_import.csv

Answer (score 0):

Something is holding a lock on that database. It is likely a previous run of `neo4j-admin` or a running database. You can find out what by running

```
lsof | grep store_lock
```

Comment: Hi fran.hartm
I was able to resolve the issue. But now I am not able to see the created nodes in the neo4j browser.
And when I start/restart the service the browser says the site cannot be reached

Comment: 2019-09-04 10:28:39.339+0000 INFO [o.n.u.i.b.ImportLogic] Import completed successfully, took 717ms. Imported:
  3 nodes
  0 relationships
  9 properties

Comment: And the server status is active. but i am not able to reach the browser. If i delete the DB and the start the server, then i am able to reach the browser

Comment: You need to 1. stop the server, run the import, start the server - make sure the server points to the correct graph.db folder (in neo4j.conf).